# MERN stack How to add contacts to group?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I have a component using react-bootstrap-table-next and I would like to have functionality to add contacts to a group. How do I do this? Do I send a put request to the backend that updates the current group with an array of contacts, or do I send a put request to update each contact with a group property?

While viewing this component I currently have access to the id for the group in the url, I just need to know how to send a put request to update this group Id with the array of contacts selected from the table, or if I should somehow update each contact with a group property....

Here is the Component for AddContactsToGroup

```
import React, { createRef, Fragment, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Col,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownToggle,
  Media,
  Row,
  UncontrolledDropdown
} from 'reactstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import FalconCardHeader from '../common/FalconCardHeader';
import ButtonIcon from '../common/ButtonIcon';
import Divider from '../common/Divider'
import paginationFactory, { PaginationProvider } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {listContacts, deleteContact } from '../../actions/index';

const AddContactsToGroup = () => {
  let table = createRef();
  const contacts = useSelector((state) => state.contacts)
  

  const contactCreate = useSelector((state) => state.createContact)
  const { success:successCreate } = contactCreate

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 // columns for the table
  
const columns = [
  {
    dataField: 'firstName',

    text: 'First Name',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: firstNameFormatter,
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: 'lastName',

    text: 'Last Name',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: lastNameFormatter,
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: 'phone_number',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Phone',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: phoneFormatter,
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: 'Group',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Group',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: groupFormatter,
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: 'phone_type',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Type',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: 'created',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Created',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    sort: true,
    align: 'right',
    headerAlign: 'right'
  },
  {
    dataField: 'actions',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Actions',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: actionFormatter,
    align: 'right'
  }
];


const SelectRowInput = ({ indeterminate, rowIndex, ...rest }) => (
  <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input
      className="custom-control-input"
      {...rest}
      onChange={() => {}}
      ref={input => {
        if (input) input.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      }}
    />
    <label className="custom-control-label" />
  </div>
);

const selectRow = onSelect => ({

  mode: 'checkbox',
 
  clickToSelect: true,
  selectionHeaderRenderer: ({ mode, ...rest }) => <SelectRowInput type="checkbox" {...rest} />,
  selectionRenderer: ({ mode, ...rest }) => <SelectRowInput type={mode} {...rest} />,
  onSelect: onSelect,
  onSelectAll: onSelect
});


  const onSelect = () => {
    setImmediate(() => {
    });
  };
  
  const options = {
    custom: true,
    sizePerPage: 12,
    totalSize: contacts.length
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listContacts())
  },[dispatch, successDelete, successCreate])





 
  return (
    <Card className="mb-3">
          <Fragment>


            <ButtonIcon icon="plus" >
              {`Add ${0} Contacts`} <---- Id like this button to send the request to the backend and update the group with contacts, or update the contacts with a group....
            </ButtonIcon>


          </Fragment>
      
      </FalconCardHeader>
      <CardBody className="p-0">
        <PaginationProvider pagination={paginationFactory(options)}>
          {({ paginationProps, paginationTableProps }) => {
            const lastIndex = paginationProps.page * paginationProps.sizePerPage;
            return (
              <Fragment>
                <div className="table-responsive">
                  <BootstrapTable
                    ref={table}
                    bootstrap4
                    keyField="_id"
                    data={contacts}
                    columns={columns}
                    selectRow={selectRow(onSelect)}
                    {...paginationTableProps}
                  />
                </div>
              </Fragment>
            );
          }}
        </PaginationProvider>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default AddContactsToGroup
```